# Why does MySQL give me a foreign key constraint error on a table that I don't have?

Tags: mysql

I'm running a series of upgrade scripts. As a note, in a an earlier script, there were many of these:

> ALTER TABLE files
>     DROP FOREIGN KEY files_ibfk_1,
>     DROP FOREIGN KEY files_ibfk_2;

However, those keys did not exist….

Now I'm getting an error…:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pacsdbcmi`.`#sql-536_77`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-536_77_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`series_fk`) REFERENCES `series` (`pk`))

What is #sql-536_77 ? Can someone explain what this means? I do not have a table named #sql-536-77, nor a key in series called #sql-536_77_ibfk_1

Thanks

Comment: That's because you have rows referenced by this FK system.. You must either disable fk checks (SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0) OR disable the cascade thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there are another tables which is foreign to the parent table.`CASCADE` relation should be there.So before you `ALTER` the parent table foreign key please remove existing `CASCADES`

```
                                     OR
```

**USE**

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

**AND**

```
ALTER TABLE files DROP FOREIGN KEY files_ibfk_1, DROP FOREIGN KEY files_ibfk_2;
```

**THEN**

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

By setting the foreign key check to 0, you can able to ALTER table. Once It  was done with operations on the table, you can reset the key check to 1 again and everything is back in place now.